# Problem with Fourier coefficients

Tags: programming, syntax, fourier-analysis

I have just started using *Mathematica* with v9.0. I am trying to follow a computation from a book on Fourier series with the function $f(x)=x$ on the interval $-\pi < x < \pi$.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
f[x_] = x; 
a[0] = 1/2 Pi Integrate[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
a[n] = 1/Pi Integrate[f[x] Cos (nx), {x, -Pi, Pi}]
b[n] = 1/Pi Integrate[f[x] Sin (nx), {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

I got the same result for a[0] and a[n] as per the book; for b[n] the answer generate by *Mathematica* is 0, but the answer in the book is $\frac{2}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$. Can someone explain why is this the case?

Note: I found a post here [Fourier Coefficients in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14210/fourier-coefficients-in-mathematica) but I can't seem to follow it.

Comment: `Sin(nx)` is the product (or multiplication) of the symbol `Sin` with the symbol `nx`. You should be using `Sin[n x]`.

Comment: `Cos(nx)` will be interpreted as `Cos*nx` try: `Cos[n x]` (note the space beteen n and x, otherwise it'll be interpreted as variable called nx)

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out @ssch and jVincent. I didn't know these. Now the result is 

    $\frac{(-2n\pi \cos(n\pi) + 2\sin(n\pi)}{n^{2}\pi}$

which is again different from the book answer of $\frac{2}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$. Do you know why is this so?

Comment: @Sandra For integer $n$, you have $\sin(n\pi)=0$ and $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^{n}$. Include the $-$ sign too and the exponent becomes $n+1$. You can do this with _Mathematica_ by telling it that $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ as `Simplify[(-2 n Pi Cos[n Pi] + 2 Sin[n Pi])/(n^2 Pi), 
 Assumptions :> {n ∈ Integers}]`

Comment: Your formula for `a[0]` should be `1/(2 Pi) Integrate[f[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`.  (`1/2 Pi` is the same as `Pi/2` -- an unlikely coefficient for the integral in this context.)

Comment: @Hypnotoad, thank you for pointing this out. Now it show me the results I am looking for. Thanks again for teaching me.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks! I didn't aware of this since it show me the intended result of $0$. Glad you pointed this out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sandra, welcome to Mathematica.SE, and thank you for taking the time to format your question so nicely!

Comment: @Sandra So far your question is not really related to `Mathematica`. Try to make a viable question of it, so that there might be a constructive answer.

Comment: This question is linked in one of the answer to the  *"What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?"* question.  I hardly see how could be true that *"This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; "*. On the contrary, this is a very quotable question, so I'm voting to reopen it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I appreciate very much, that you wrote up such a nicely formatted question, although this is your first post. Therefore, let's put the comments into an answer.

**Your first issue** was that you used `( )` where you should have used `[ ]`. That's maybe not obvious for starters and I have seen this mistake very often. There are different types of braces and it's important to always use the right ones. Here is an overview

1. `[ ]` are always used when you want to call a function like `Sin[x]`.
2. `( )` are used change the order of evaluation like you would do in normal mathematics too. Therefore, you would use `a*(b+c)` to add `b` and `c` before doing the multiplication.
3. `{ }` are to construct lists, matrices and other tensors. `{1,2,3}` is a list or vector and yes, `{x,-Pi,-Pi}` is a list too.
4. `[[ ]]` is used to take parts of lists and vectors. `{x,-Pi,Pi}[[3]]` would give you the `Pi`. See the documentation to [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) to learn what else is possible.

**Your second issue** was that you assumed `nx` is the multiplication of `n` and `x` which it is not. You have to understand that when you use `var` it would be impossible to decide for *Mathematica* whether you mean the variable name `var` or the multiplication `v*a*r`. Therefore, always put explicit multiplication `n*x` which is the most clear way or leave a space between them. A third option which is not recommended in this situation is to add parenthesis. `n(x)` is interpreted as `n*x` too. Looks odd here but this notation is very common in expressions like `(x + 1)(x + 2)`.

**Your third issue** that the expression is the hardest one because in general it is not obvious and sometimes even not possible to force *Mathematica* to simplify an expression into a form *you* prefer. Additional to the solution to Hypnotoad using

```
Simplify[(-2 n Pi Cos[n Pi] + 2 Sin[n Pi])/(n^2 Pi), 
  Assumptions :> {n \[Element] Integers}]
```

you can use `Refine` which

> gives the form of expr that would be obtained if symbols in it were replaced by explicit numerical expressions satisfying the assumptions assum.

```
Refine[(-2 n Pi Cos[n Pi] + 2 Sin[n Pi])/(n^2 Pi), n \[Element] Integers]
```

**Your fourth issue** is about the right hand side of your definition of `a[n]` and `b[n]`. When your goal is to define a general coefficient where you can change the value of `n` to calculate for instance `b[5]`, then those lines will not work. Try yourself what happens if you use `b[4]`. To make it work, you have to use

```
b[n_] = 1/Pi Integrate[f[x] Sin [n*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Note the underscore! Now it's possible to calculate `b[4]`. When you want to know why this is, you should start reading [the tutorial about defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) and follow the references. (Thanks to caya to point out that I had forgotten this issue)

Comment: thank you for your graceful recap of the issues and answers.

Comment: @halirutan, I think you forgot to mention the all important missing pattern n_ in LHS.

Comment: @caya Thanks, I added it as last point.

Comment: One more alternative notation for multiplication that you didn't mention is whitespace. It's a nice way to make things look more like traditional mathematical notation.

Comment: @silvascientist why didn't? _"or leave a space between them"_, right there.